# How to create a button programmatically with for loop in swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, for-loop

I created buttons with for loop and i want to print button number when pressed to button. How can i do this?

```
for x in 0..<5 {
   let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(x) * view.frame.size.width + 10 , y: 40, width: view.frame.size.width - 20, height: 30))
   buttonKontrol = x
   print(buttonKontrol)
   button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
   button.backgroundColor = .white
   button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        
   button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btntapped), for: .touchUpInside)
   scrollView.addSubview(button)
}
```

and objc func:

```
@objc func btntapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("button tapped")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various ways to do that...

1. find the frame of the tapped button (not a good approach, but for your simple example it could work)
2. use the `.tag` property of the button
3. evaluate the `.currentTitle` property of the button
4. add the buttons to an array... on tap, use `let buttonNumber = btnsArray.firstIndex(of: sender)`

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways, but a 'Swifty' way might be like this:

```
final class TargetAction {
    let work: () -> Void

    init(_ work: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.work = work
    }

    @objc func action() {
        work()
    }
}
    
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var tas: [TargetAction] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        (0...4).forEach { x in
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(x) * 50 , y: 40, width: 44, height: 44))
            button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
            button.setTitle("\(x)", for: .normal)
            let ta =
                TargetAction {
                    print(x)
                }
            tas.append(ta)
            button.addTarget(ta, action: #selector(TargetAction.action), for: .touchUpInside)
            view.addSubview(button)
        }
    }
}
```